# Opening .txt Files stored in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with one column containing .txt files.

***How can I access the text files?***

[image: e]

When I try:

```
f = open(df.embedding_file.iloc[0], "r")
```

I get the following error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'doc_embeddings_1.txt'
```

Comment: The error's pretty clear. It says the file is not found. Is the file present at the same location from where you are running this script?

Comment: You may be missing fullpath

Comment: @Mayank Porwal I assumed the files are stored in the dataframe row? Are you saying it is more likely the df only contains names of files stored somewhere else?

Comment: @Sigmund Yes, that's exactly what it is. DF just has the names to the files, not the actual files.

Comment: I closed the question as a duplicate, but now that I'm reading the comments, apparently the problem was more fundamental. It seems like you just had a brain fart, in which case there's no real point reopening the question, but just in case you're genuinely still confused, you could [edit] to clarify, like "I don't understand why I'm getting this error because [x]". If you want more tips, check out [ask].